# Find specific variable in array inside array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to search an array if it contains an variable "Foo"

```
details={u'firstName': u'Test', u'activeSubscriptions': [{u'productCode': u'BBB', u'name': u'Bar'}, {u'productCode': u'FFF', u'name': u'Foo'}
```

I have done like this:

```
subscriptions_name = data['activeSubscriptions'][0]['name']
```

but this only works for the first data in the array.

How could I get the name of `FFF` if the data is not placed consistently?

Comment: Does it have to be `FFF` or do you want to check value of `name` for all `dicts` in `activeSubscriptions`?

Comment: Note that it is not an array but a `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching by `productCode` in your `activeSubscriptions` array, you are looking for this:

```
>>> details={'firstName': 'Test', 'activeSubscriptions': [{'productCode': 'BBB', 'name': 'Bar'}, {'productCode': 'FFF', 'name': 'Foo'}]}
>>> product_code_search_key = 'FFF'
>>> for subscription in details['activeSubscriptions']:        
...     if subscription and subscription.get('productCode','') and subscription['productCode'] == product_code_search_key:
...         print subscription['name']
...         break
... 
>>> Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten your list recursively and search inside it:

```
def flatten(l):
    res = []
    for e in l:
        if type(e) is dict:
            tmp = e.values()
            res += flatten(tmp)
         elif type(e) is list:
             tmp = e[:]
             res += flatten(tmp)
         else:
             res += e
    return res

if "Foo" in flatten(list)
```

Edit: for performance reason, it is unnecessary to compute the array and search inside it. Following a version that just search inside the array:

```
def is_in_superlist(l, m):
    for e in l:
        if type(e) is dict:
            return is_in_superlist(e.values(), m)
         elif type(e) is list:
             return is_in_superlist(e, m)
         else:
             if e == m:
                 return True
    return False

is_in_superlist(list, "Foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate the array of dictonary and acheive like below

```
details={'firstName': 'Test', 'activeSubscriptions': [{'productCode': 'BBB', 'name': 'Bar'}, {'productCode': 'FFF', 'name': 'Foo'}]}

for i in details['activeSubscriptions']:        
    if 'Foo' in i.values():
        print i
```